# How to use specific proxy address for specific application in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, proxy, ip, network-protocols

I have a chat client application. When I connect to internet & chat with other person via that application, the application uses the IP of my ISP to connect to internet & transfers data via that IP. Can I use a specific proxy address such:(50.17.156.80:3128) to force that chat application to connect to internet & to transfer data via this IP ?

Here This is the IP: 50.17.156.80 & this is the port: 3128

Note that: If we want, we can use proxy address in our browser to connect to internet.

So, can i use the same system for the chat application so that it will transfer data via that proxy IP ? If yes, Please tell me how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Proxifier and add a proxyserver then 
define a rule to that chat application uses this proxy server.

1. Proxy Servers...
2. Proxification rules...set